# Platform not supported for Tensorflow on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: software-installation, python, c++, google, pip

Tensorflow is a numerical computation software http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#binary_installation

The installation instruction says to simply `pip install` on Ubuntu but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo -H pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

My Ubuntu version:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

My kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubi 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Any clues on how to install tensorflow in ubuntu or to resolve the platform problem?**

Comment: What does `uname -a` report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, because I used the wrong pip version (python 3). I fixed it by installing pip2.7 as described here: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/

You basically download the file **get-pip.py**

and install pip2.7 with

```
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

now you can run

```
python2.7 -m pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

you need to be a superuser and tensorflow will install.

cheers

Comment: Indeed, using pip2 works: `pip2 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

Comment: You alternatively could just change the `0.5.0-cp27` to `0.5.0-cp3` and bam installed for python3